# types of t tests for hypothesis testing

Tags: t-test

I am confused about the difference between the below two formulas to compute the t statistic. Please explain how they are different and when to use which.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulae refer to the two-sample t-test with $n_1$ and $n_2$ being the sample sizes, $\bar{x}_1$ and $\bar{x}_2$ the two sample means, and where it is assumed that the two samples have equal variance, represented by the pooled variance:
$$s^2= s_p^2 = \frac{(n_1- 1) s_1^2+ (n_2- 1)  s_2^2}{n_1 + n_2- 2 
}$$
where $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ are the sample variances. Note that $\sqrt{s^2} =s_p$

In the first formula, the null hypothesis is that the true population means are equal, and this hypothesis is rejected if the test statistic is large enough.

In the second formula, the null hypothesis is that the difference between the true population means equals µ<sub>1</sub> - µ<sub>2</sub>. If this difference is assumed to be zero then the second formula is the same as the first one; otherwise the test assumes that µ<sub>1</sub> - µ<sub>2</sub> = some value m, and this hypothesis is rejected if the test statistic is large enough.

You can find a [detailed description here](https://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/two-sample-t-test-equal-variances/).